# Highcharts / Highstock scroll default position

Tags: highcharts

I have a HighStock charge with a scrollbar very similar to this one

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/3.1.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/navigator-disabled/

```
    Highcharts.stockChart('container', {


        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 1
        },

        title: {
            text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
        },

        navigator: {
            enabled: false
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'AAPL Stock Price',
            data: data,
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            }
        }]
    });
```

I want the default scroll position to be somewhere in the middle of the chart though, is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [`xAxis.setExtremes`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/Axis.setExtremes) on the [`chart.events.load`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/chart.events.load) call. A simple example (using arbitrary 1 year range):

```
  chart: {
    events: {
      load: function() {
        this.xAxis[0].setExtremes(
          Date.UTC(2013, 0, 1),
          Date.UTC(2013, 11, 31)
        );
      }
    }
  },
```

Example [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/0Lu5uspz/).

If you need to determine what your "middle" is it can depend on your data source where you could pre-calculate it or you could do it also on the `chart.events.load` call.

For fun I added the mid-point calculations. This uses moment.js because it is much easier than rolling your own time methods.

```
minX = data[0][0];
maxX = data[data.length - 1][0];
midX = minX + ((maxX - minX) / 2);

var midDate = new Date(midX);
var startDate = moment(midDate);
var endDateMoment = moment(midDate);
startDate.subtract(1.5, 'months');
endDateMoment.add(1.5, 'months');
```

Note that I am addinng/subtracting 1.5 months to make your 3 month range selector valid. The moment.js library rounds those up to 2 months. You get the idea though. So your `setExtremes` becomes:

```
    this.xAxis[0].setExtremes(
      startDate.valueOf(), //.valueOf() in this context converts to javascript time
      endDateMoment.valueOf()
    );
```

And here is live [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/0Lu5uspz/1/).